# Discuss non-singular of this 2x2 block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a p × p non-singular symmetric matrix $\Sigma$, determine the condition on the entries of
the diagonal matrix $D = Diag(d_1, . . . , d_p)$ for the following 2p × 2p matrix to be non-singular:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \Sigma& \Sigma-D\\
\Sigma -D & \Sigma
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}

My attempt: I use the theorem that the above is non-singular if and only if $\Sigma - (\Sigma-D) \Sigma^{-1}(\Sigma-D) $ is non-singular. The theorem is general for any two by two block matrix.  I can simplify from $\Sigma - (\Sigma-D) \Sigma^{-1}(\Sigma-D) $ to  $2D - D \Sigma^{-1}D$.

Comment: If $2D-D\Sigma^{-1} D$ is non-singular, then $D$ must also be non-singular. So then you can focus on $2I - \Sigma^{-1} D$. I guess a condition that works is "$2$ is not an eigenvalue of $\Sigma^{-1} D$"?

Comment: If  $2D - D \Sigma^{-1}D$ is on-singular, why D must also be non-singular?

Comment: If $D$ is singular, then there exists $v$ such that $Dv=0$. Then $(2D-D\Sigma^{-1} D) v = 0$ so $2D-D\Sigma^{-1} D$ is also singular.

Comment: Since D needs to be singular, one condition is that no $d_i$ can be 0. But I notice that we don't need that condition that $\Sigma$ is symmetric.

Comment: Since $2D-D\Sigma^{-1}D=D(2I-\Sigma^{-1}D)$, it is nonsingular if and only if $D$ is nonsingular and $2$ is not an eigenvalue of $\Sigma^{-1}D$.