# How to prove this inverse matrix identity?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let ***L*** be an $(n − 1) \times n$ matrix such that ***LL'*** $= I_{n−1}$ (where $'$ denotes the transpose) and ***La*** = **0** for an $n × 1$ vector ***a***.
Prove that the following result holds for any $n × n$ non-singular symmetric matrix ***A***:

$(LAL')^{-1} = LA^{-1}L' - \frac{LA^{-1}aa'A^{-1}L'}{a'A^{-1}a}$

My attempt: The idea is simple, I just want to show that $LAL'$ times RHS is identity. But I couldn't solve that. How to prove:

$$LAL'\left(LA^{-1}L' - \frac{LA^{-1}aa'A^{-1}L'}{a'A^{-1}a}\right)=I$$

Comment: Are A and a'  unique or arbitrary?

Comment: @DavidRaveh Both are given.

Comment: Where is that expression coming from? Are you sure the denominator is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely false, as $a'A^{-1}a$ can be zero, e.g. when $L=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix},\,a=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ -1\end{bmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ &-1\end{bmatrix}$, $LAL'=\begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}$ is invertible but $a'A^{-1}a=0$.

However, $a'A^{-1}a\ne0$ is sufficient for the equality to hold.

---

It is clearer to consider a more general setting. Suppose $L\in\mathbb F^{(n-1)\times n},\,A\in\mathbb F^{n\times n},\,R\in\mathbb F^{n\times(n-1)}$ are three matrices and $u,v\in\mathbb F^n$ are two vectors such that $A$ is invertible and
$$
LR=I_n,\quad Lu=0,\quad v'R=0,\quad v'A^{-1}u\ne0.
$$
Since $Lu=0$ but $v'A^{-1}u\ne0$, the row vector $v'A^{-1}$ is not a linear combination of the rows of $L$. Hence it is linearly independent of the rows of $L$. It follows that $\begin{bmatrix}L\\ v'A^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$ is invertible. In fact, we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}L\\ v'A^{-1}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\left(I_n-\frac{uv'A^{-1}}{v'A^{-1}u}\right)R& \frac{u}{v'A^{-1}u}\end{bmatrix}
=I_n.\tag{1}
$$
Similarly, $\begin{bmatrix}R&A^{-1}u\end{bmatrix}$ is also invertible:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}L\left(I_n-\frac{A^{-1}uv'}{v'A^{-1}u}\right)\\ \frac{v'}{v'A^{-1}u}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}R&A^{-1}u\end{bmatrix}
=I_n.\tag{2}
$$
Now note that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}L\\ v'A^{-1}\end{bmatrix}
A
\begin{bmatrix}R&A^{-1}u\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}LAR&0\\ 0&v'A^{-1}u\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since all three matrices on the left are invertible, so is the RHS. In particular, $LAR$ must be invertible. Taking inverses on both sides of the equality above, we obtain
$$
\begin{bmatrix}L\left(I_n-\frac{A^{-1}uv'}{v'A^{-1}u}\right)\\ \frac{v'}{v'A^{-1}u}\end{bmatrix}
A^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}\left(I_n-\frac{uv'A^{-1}}{v'A^{-1}u}\right)R& \frac{u}{v'A^{-1}u}\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}(LAR)^{-1}&0\\ 0&\frac{1}{v'A^{-1}u}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
(LAR)^{-1}
&=
L\left(I_n-\frac{A^{-1}uv'}{v'A^{-1}u}\right)
A^{-1}
\left(I_n-\frac{uv'A^{-1}}{v'A^{-1}u}\right)R\\
&=
L\left(A^{-1}-\frac{A^{-1}uv'A^{-1}}{v'A^{-1}u}\right)R.
\end{aligned}
$$
In your case, simply put $R=L'$ and $u=v=a$. Note that we don't need the assumption that $A$ is symmetric here.

---

**Remark. How can I directly verify that $LAR\cdot
L\left(A^{-1}-\frac{A^{-1}uv'A^{-1}}{v'A^{-1}u}\right)R = I_{n-1}?
$**

Let
$$
\Pi_1=I_n-\frac{uv'A^{-1}}{v'A^{-1}u}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\Pi_2=I_n-\frac{A^{-1}uv'}{v'A^{-1}u}.
$$
We want to show that
$$
(LAR)(L\Pi_2A^{-1}R)=I_{n-1}.
$$
The key observation is that
$$
RL\Pi_2=\Pi_2,
$$
because $\Pi_2$ is a projection onto $\operatorname{im}(R)$. It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
(LAR)(L\Pi_2A^{-1}R)
&=LA(RL\Pi_2)A^{-1}R\\
&=LA\Pi_2A^{-1}R\\
&=LA(\Pi_2A^{-1})R\\
&=LA(A^{-1}\Pi_1)R\\
&=(L\Pi_1)R\\
&=LR\\
&=I_{n-1}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Very neat solution.

Comment: Your first example is not correct. If L is the row vector (1, 1), then LL'= 2 not identity.

Comment: Can you explain the row vector $a'A^{-1}$ is linearly independent of the rows of $L$?

Comment: $$
\pmatrix{L\\ a'A^{-1}}
\pmatrix{L'-\frac{aa'A^{-1}L'}{a'A^{-1}a}& \frac{a}{a'A^{-1}a}}
=I_n.
$$ This is not true. The two parts are not the same size. $a'A^{-1}a$ is only a scalar.

Comment: @Jonathen (1) That $LL'=2$ doesn't matter. You may scale $L$ by $1/\sqrt{2}$. (2) If $a'A$ is a linear combination of the rows of $L$, then $a'A=x'L$ for some row vector $x$. Therefore $a'Aa=x'La=0$. (3) I don't understand your question. Yes, $a'A^{-1}a$ is a scalar. Which “two parts” are not the same?

Comment: @Jonathen This can be seen from $n-1\ge\operatorname{rank}(L)\ge\operatorname{rank}(LL')=n-1$. Alternatively, the rows of $L$ are linearly independent because the equation $x'L=0$ has only the trivial solution: $x'L=0\ \Rightarrow\ x'=x'I_{n-1}=x'LL'=(x'L)L'=0$.

Comment: @Jonathen Please read more carefully before commenting and stating that some things are not correct. Also, please formulate clear sentences.

Comment: @user1551 In fact, we have
$$
\begin{bmatrix}L\\ a'A^{-1}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\left(I_n-\frac{aa'A^{-1}}{a'A^{-1}a}\right)L'& \frac{a}{a'A^{-1}a}\end{bmatrix}
=I_n.
$$ I mean this equation is incorrect.

Comment: @Jonathen I don't see any flaws here. You may just multiply out the two matrices on the left to verify that the result is $I_n$.

Comment: @user1551 $$a'A^{-1} (I_n-\frac{aa'A^{-1}}{a'A^{-1}a})L' = a'A^{-1} - a'A^{-1}L'$$
Notice that $a'A^{-1}$ is row vector 1xn, but $a'A^{-1}L'$ is a row vector 1x(n-1)

Comment: @Jonathen No, it's $a'A^{-1}L'-a'A^{-1}L'=0$.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you so much!! I have another problem, if you have interest to solve. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4535766/discuss-non-singular-of-this-2x2-block-matrix